# Can you suggest a program for shutting down many Win7 PCs at set times?

Tags: windows-7

Can anyone suggest a program for shutting down many Windows 7 PCs at set times? I need to shot down over 1000 PCs every night. We have Active Directory and Windows 200 R2 servers.

Thanks
John

Comment: I think shutdown command supports remote hosts. I suppose they're all in the same AD domain.

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to assign a scheduled task to perform the shutdown, via Group Policy:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725745.aspx

Answer (score 2):

you can use [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) and execute *shutdown* command.

ps. indeed if computers are in same domain - you dont even need psexec.

Answer (score 1):

You could batch script it...

`Shutdown /s /t 0 /m \\computer1

   Shtudown /s /t 0 /m \\computer2`

Then schedule the job to run on one of your DCs, have the job run as a Domain Admin.

Answer (score 0):

You want a script which does this for each named machine:

`shutdown -s -t 0 -f -m \\machinename`